# Can't connect the laptop to TV using wireless display (Chromecast works fine though)

Tags: android-tv, google-tv

I got a new TV with Google TV and Android 11.

I am able to cast tabs in Chrome to it from my PC. But when I try to connect to the TV using the wireless display feature , it
doesn't show anything.

[image: https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/B4FCZWaui4mhfH4zKurpNc-1200-80.png]

What should I do?

Comment: The Windows Wireless Display function requires a display that supports Miracast or WiGig. Are you sure your TV supports one of those standards?

Comment: @Robert How do I check miracast compatiblity?

Comment: Also how to enable it?

Comment: Have you checked the technical specifications of your TV? As you don't tell us the exact me del name and manufacturer you have to check it yourself.

Comment: @Robert Miracast is not mentioned in it. But since it's android TV, why can't I just enable it myself? I tried an app. It said "3rd parties app are not allowed to install miracast since android 8.0". Why can't I just override this setting and force enable it?

Comment: There's a guide to enable Miracast (WiFi Direct) on [XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-enable-miracast.3565852/) (need root). Whether it's possible or working, is another question.

Comment: @AndrewT. I am not sure if just changing a property is enough on recent Android versions. A [newer guide from 2019 for Android 9](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-how-to-enable-miracast-for-pixel.3888780/) mentions that a lot of system libraries have to replaced as well. So I assume Miracast is no longer included in Android so you can not just "enable it".